# Hidden Markov Model: Robustness and `Forbidden` Transitions

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have an issue while using a HMM to estimate the state of a system where the state-transition matrix is a block-diagonal matrix. Specifically I have an issue with robustness and the HMM keeps transitioning rapidly to unlikely states when presented with measurement errors.

The reason for this seems to be that residual probabilities get amplified in the presence measurement errors. An extreme case can be found in the attached example, where the model transitions to an improbable state after only 5 iterations although there is no viable path between the states.

Is there a way to dampen(?) the model so that transitions require more time? Since I don't know the initial state, I would like to allow transitions to another block with a small residual probability, just *not that fast*.

### Code

```py
import numpy as np


class HMM:

    def __init__(self, transition_matrix: np.ndarray, state_probabilities: np.ndarray):
        self._T = transition_matrix
        self._alphas_current = state_probabilities

    def update(self, observation_probabilities: np.ndarray):
        alphas_new = (self._T @ self._alphas_current) * observation_probabilities
        self._alphas_current = alphas_new / alphas_new.sum()
        state_idx, p = max(enumerate(self._alphas_current.flatten().tolist()), key=lambda i: i[1])
        print(f"Estimated state {state_idx:d} with p={p:.4f}")

    def print_state_probability(self, state_idx: int):
        print(f"Current probability of state {state_idx}: {self._alphas_current.flatten()[state_idx]:.2e}")


def simulate_observation_probabilities(state_idx: int, p: float) -> np.ndarray:
    p_default = (1 - p) / 3
    observation_probabilities = np.array([p_default] * 4)
    observation_probabilities[state_idx] = p
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(f"Simulating state {state_idx} with p_observation={p:.2f}")
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    return observation_probabilities.reshape(-1, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize HMM
    T = np.array([[0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.1, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1],
                  [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9]])
    initial_probabilities = np.array([0.25] * 4).reshape(-1, 1)
    hmm = HMM(T, initial_probabilities)

    # Simulate state 1 with p=0.9
    print('============== BEGIN MODEL INITIALIZATION ================')
    observation_probabilities_1 = simulate_observation_probabilities(1, 0.9)
    for i in range(5):
        hmm.update(observation_probabilities_1)
    print('\n============== BEGIN OUTLIER SIMULATION ================')
    # state change: Simulate state 3 with p=0.9
    hmm.print_state_probability(3)
    observation_probabilities_3 = simulate_observation_probabilities(3, 0.9)
    for i in range(5):
        hmm.update(observation_probabilities_3)
```

### Output

````
============== BEGIN MODEL INITIALIZATION ================
-----------------------------------------------
Simulating state 1 with p_observation=0.90
-----------------------------------------------
Estimated state 1 with p=0.9000
Estimated state 1 with p=0.9916
Estimated state 1 with p=0.9956
Estimated state 1 with p=0.9957
Estimated state 1 with p=0.9957

============== BEGIN OUTLIER SIMULATION ================
Current probability of state 3: 1.05e-07
-----------------------------------------------
Simulating state 3 with p_observation=0.90
-----------------------------------------------
Estimated state 1 with p=0.8966
Estimated state 1 with p=0.8172
Estimated state 1 with p=0.7525
Estimated state 1 with p=0.6753
Estimated state 3 with p=0.4979`
```
````